# Azure direct line customization

Tags: azure, adaptive-cards

my adaptive card contains many fields to be captured  (more than 18)
it is very cumbersome to edit it inside the chatbot window.
is it possible to open the content the exact adaptive card in separate URL and allow user to edit and save.

Comment: What channel are you using? Is it Webchat?

Comment: yes it is the webchat

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the functionality you are looking for by means of Web Chat's available features. Whether or not you want to open an adaptive card in a separate window is entirely up to you. The below samples enables your bot to receive data from / send data to the hosting page. Whether you use an adaptive card or some other type of form, that data can easily be shared with your bot. And your bot can easily respond, accordingly.

Let's say you have a "form" already built, you could use either of these two methods for posting data to your bot. Either can do so in response to some input from the user on the hosting page (e.g. clicking a submit button that then collects the user's input data before sending it).

- [04.api/d.post-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event)
  Demonstrates sending a new activity following user interaction
- [04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities)
  Demonstrates attaching data to an already existing activity following user interaction

These two samples show how the bot's response can trigger an event on the hosting page. For example, the user indicates they want to fill out a form, the bot responds by sending an event, Web Chat detects the event and opens the "form" to be completed.

- [04.api/j.redux-actions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/j.redux-actions)
  Demonstrates using Web Chat's store for triggering an event on the hosting page
- [04.api/c.incoming-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/c.incoming-activity-event)
  Demonstrates using event listeners for triggering an event on the hosting page.

Both sets ultimately achieve the same thing. It's only a matter of which one meets your needs better in both cases. Once you have your "form" setup, you just need to integrate into the functionalities presented above.

Alternatively, you could break up your 18 question form sending several smaller, more consumable, adaptive cards one after the other. It's simpler to build and you could group like questions together. Just food for thought.